# Boxplot names returning integer instead of name

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot, outliers

I am trying to use the $names operator on my OutVals (outliers) to find the class these outliers are associated to and then put the outliers and their class name inside a data frame so I can see clearly from which class these outliers came from.

However, when trying to implement this, my class names return as "1", "2" etc... and not "Van", "Bus etc.. as it is in the dataset.

Have I missed something or am I approaching this completely wrong?
The goal is to get the outliers in the data and place them inside a table which shows from which class the outliers came from

Any help would be appreciated

I have shown my data frame as well as my reproduceable code below

```
library(reshape2)
vehData <-
  structure(
    list(
      Samples = 1:6,
      Comp = c(95L, 91L, 104L, 93L, 85L,
               107L),
      Circ = c(48L, 41L, 50L, 41L, 44L, 57L),
      D.Circ = c(83L,
                 84L, 106L, 82L, 70L, 106L),
      Rad.Ra = c(178L, 141L, 209L, 159L,
                 205L, 172L),
      Pr.Axis.Ra = c(72L, 57L, 66L, 63L, 103L, 50L),
      Max.L.Ra = c(10L,
                   9L, 10L, 9L, 52L, 6L),
      Scat.Ra = c(162L, 149L, 207L, 144L, 149L,
                  255L),
      Elong = c(42L, 45L, 32L, 46L, 45L, 26L),
      Pr.Axis.Rect = c(20L,
                       19L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 28L),
      Max.L.Rect = c(159L, 143L, 158L, 143L,
                     144L, 169L),
      Sc.Var.Maxis = c(176L, 170L, 223L, 160L, 241L, 280L),
      Sc.Var.maxis = c(379L, 330L, 635L, 309L, 325L, 957L),
      Ra.Gyr = c(184L,
                 158L, 220L, 127L, 188L, 264L),
      Skew.Maxis = c(70L, 72L, 73L,
                     63L, 127L, 85L),
      Skew.maxis = c(6L, 9L, 14L, 6L, 9L, 5L),
      Kurt.maxis = c(16L,
                     14L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 9L),
      Kurt.Maxis = c(187L, 189L, 188L, 199L,
                     180L, 181L),
      Holl.Ra = c(197L, 199L, 196L, 207L, 183L, 183L),
      Class = c("van", "van", "saab", "van", "bus", "bus")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  6L), class = "data.frame")

#Remove outliers function
removeOutliers <- function(data) {
  OutVals <- boxplot(data)$out
  
  namesforgroups <- boxplot(OutVals)$names #get group name of the outliers
  
  dataf <- as.data.frame(OutVals, col.names = namesforgroups)#dataframe of outlier + names
  
  print(OutVals) # show all outliers
  
  remOutliers <- sapply(data, function(x) x[!x %in% OutVals]) #remove outliers from data
  return (remOutliers)
}

#Remove class column and sample number
vehDataRemove1 <- vehData[, -1]
vehDataRemove2 <- vehDataRemove1[,-19]
vehData <- vehDataRemove2 #assign to new variable
vehClass <- vehData$Class #store original class names

#Begin removing outliers
removeOutliers1 <- removeOutliers(vehData) #remove first set of outliers
removeOutliers2 <- removeOutliers(removeOutliers1) #test again for more and remove
```

Output data frame
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about which row/class name the outlier is tied to is not provided in the boxplot object. You have to get it yourself. What is given is the column that the outlier came from, inside `boxplot(data)$group`, so you can use `which` to see which row it was from, and use that to get what class it is. I rewrote your function and it now prints a table of the outlier value, the column it came from, and the row/class it came from. There are 5 outliers from 3 rows in the first iteration, and no outliers in the second iteration - makes sense because they've been removed.

```
removeOutliers <- function(data, class) {
  x=boxplot(data)
  
  OutVals <- x$out
  
  columns <- x$group #get group name of the outliers
  ind=numeric()
  classes=c()
  if (length(columns) > 0) {
    for (i in 1:length(columns)) {
      rows=which(data[,columns[i]]==OutVals[i])
      ind=union(ind, rows)
      classes=c(classes, class[rows])
    }
    dt=data.frame(OutVals, columns, classes) # show all outliers
    print(dt)
    return (list(data[-ind,], class[-ind]))
  }
  return(list(data, class))
}

#Remove class column and sample number
vehData1 <- vehData[, -c(1,20)]
vehClass <- vehData$Class #store original class names

#Begin removing outliers
removeOutliers1 <- removeOutliers(vehData1, vehClass) #remove first set of outliers
  OutVals columns classes
1     103       5     bus
2      52       6     bus
3       6       6     bus
4     127      14     bus
5      14      15    saab

removeOutliers2 <- removeOutliers(removeOutliers1[[1]], removeOutliers1[[2]])
```

The first function returns a data frame with the outlier rows removed. The second function returns a table containing information about each outlier (the class, the column, and the value).

```
removeOutliers=function(data) {
  x=boxplot(data %>% select(-Class), plot=FALSE)
  outlierRows=c()
  for (i in 1:length(x$out)) {
    outlierRows=c(outlierRows, which(data[,x$group[i]]==x$out[i]))
  }
  return(data[-outlierRows,])
}

getOutliers=function(data) {
  x=boxplot(data %>% select(-Class))
  outlierInfo=data.frame()
  for (i in 1:length(x$out)) {
    rows=which(data[,x$group[i]]==x$out[i])
    outlierInfo=bind_rows(outlierInfo, data.frame(class=data$Class[rows], 
                                                  value=x$out[i],
                                                  column=names(data)[x$group[i]]))
  }
  return(outlierInfo)
}

removeOutliers(vehData)
  Samples Comp Circ D.Circ Rad.Ra Pr.Axis.Ra Max.L.Ra Scat.Ra Elong Pr.Axis.Rect Max.L.Rect
1       1   95   48     83    178         72       10     162    42           20        159
2       2   91   41     84    141         57        9     149    45           19        143
4       4   93   41     82    159         63        9     144    46           19        143
  Sc.Var.Maxis Sc.Var.maxis Ra.Gyr Skew.Maxis Skew.maxis Kurt.maxis Kurt.Maxis Holl.Ra Class
1          176          379    184         70          6         16        187     197   van
2          170          330    158         72          9         14        189     199   van
4          160          309    127         63          6         10        199     207   van

getOutliers(vehData)
  class value     column
1   bus   103 Pr.Axis.Ra
2   bus    52   Max.L.Ra
3   bus     6   Max.L.Ra
4   bus   127 Skew.Maxis
5  saab    14 Skew.maxis
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't quite understand all the code. I am very new to R.  I don't quite understand how removeOutliers1[[2]] works. From the function you done return(list(data, class)). This attached the class to removeOutliers1? and so removeOutliers1[[2]] now holds the classes. But why would we pass these same classes to removeOutliers2. Should we not have done removeOutliers2 <- removeOutliers(removeOutliers[[1]], vehClass) ? so we pass the data of removeOutliers through [[1]] and then vehClass for the class? So we can also identify which class the second set of outliers belong to?

Comment: The way I wrote the code, removeOutliers[[1]] contains the new data frame without the outliers, and removeOutliers[[2]] contains the classes for each row. So we would want to pass removeOutliers[[1]] and removeOutliers[[2]] to removeOutliers. If you passed the original vehClass to removeOutliers via removeOutliers(removeOutliers[[1]], vehClass), it would be messed up because vehClass has more classes than there are rows in removeOutliers[[1]]. Also, removeOutliers(removeOutliers[[1]], removeOutliers[[2]]) doesn't do anything because we've already removed the outliers.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! Would there be a way to create a data frame that held all the outliers and their classes, each time remove outliers function is run, it just adds the new set of outliers to the class in the data frame. So we're just updating a single data frame with new outliers each time more outliers are detected

Comment: Wasn't sure if you're interested in the data with the outliers removed, or have particular interest in the outliers themselves. So I wrote two functions above.

Comment: This is incredible! Thanks again so much! Just to confirm: The removeOutliers function will return the data and display it without the outliers within it. To see the outliers inside the data I use getOutliers() function which won't remove them but just show me the ones that need to be removed and from which column and class?

Comment: The functions work really well on this smaller test sample however when I try and apply it to my full dataset containing 846 obs the first function gives me an error which is " Error in data.frame(OutVals, columns, classes) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 55, 123" Would you know how I could go about fixing this function?